# Using Object variables to reference new data types/objects

Tags: java, oop, reference-type

I have had a burning question for a long time now, relating to the Java syntax and why it allows this:

```
Object object1 = new Integer();
```

Why can we declare child classes using Object as a reference?
Also, let's take a look at this piece of code:

```
public class Parent{}    
public class Child extends Parent{}

public static void main(String[] args){
   Parent var1 = new Child();                
   Object var2 = new Child();
   Object var3 = new Parent();                
}
```

All three cases will run, as I have tried this. The question is, does it matter whether I use Object to reference a new object/variable or the actual class name? 
Also, how does the reference type selected affect the program and code? Does a certain reference type like "Object" take up less memory or make the program more efficient?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it does matter, you can't access Child or Parent class methods with var2, var3. Compiler wont let it happen.

Comment: The actual object will always stay the same, regardless which type you use to access it. So `Object obj = new Person ();` won't be converted to Object, it's always a Object of the Type Person. You Just don't see the Methods of Person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is, does it matter whether I use Object to reference a new object/variable or the actual class name?

Yes, it does. If you use the general interface/class name for your reference it will allow you to use **dynamic dispatch**, which means to decouple the client code from concrete implementations. 
Let's say you have `Cat` and `Dog` classes which extend `Animal` class. Both classes overide `makeNoise()` method. Then you may write a code:

```
Animal animal = animalFactory.getAnimal(); 
animal.makeNoise();
```

Which is not dependent on a concrete implementation of animal: it may be `Dog` or `Cat` whatever you need. The advantage of this approach is that your code is less prone to changes. Less changes -> less bugs.
But it is important to mention, that you may only call the methods which are declared in the variable type. So, if your variable is `Object` type only `Object` methods are available to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Because `public class Parent{}` is the exact same as

```
public class Parent extends java.lang.Object {
}
```

The compiler adds the "extends java.lang.Object" if you don't specify any super type.

Comment: But what effect does the reference type have on the programming? Does an Object reference take up more memory and computing power than say a Parent reference? Or is it just bad programming to declare everything as Objects? Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't very useful to make everything an `Object`, (the reference type has no effect on memory, computing power, efficiency or anything else) - `Object` doesn't have many public methods. Instead [**program to an interface**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Answer (score 0):

For clarification:

Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

As [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

And in terms of OOP that's called `type polymorphism` which means by example:

If S is a subtype of T, the subtyping relation is often written S <: T, to mean that any term of type S can be safely used in a context where a term of type T is expected As this [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) said.

Because of that any data types subtype can be assigned to Object instance

Answer (score 0):

In terms of efficiency I don't think it makes any difference since you have that instance of the object type anyways.

The main advantages of using it might be to make Polymorphism. For instance

```
Object var1 = new GrandParent();                
Object var2 = new Child();
Object var3 = new Parent();
List<Object> object_list = new ArrayList<>();
object_list.add(var1);
object_list.add(var2);
object_list.add(var3);
```

Of course this doesn't make much sense since you wouldn't have any advantage. But if you used an **Interface** you could call a method without specifing the type. Something like this:

```
IPerson var1 = new GrandParent();                
IPerson var2 = new Child();
IPerson var3 = new Parent();
List<IPerson > object_list = new ArrayList<>();
object_list.add(var1);
object_list.add(var2);
object_list.add(var3);

for(IPerson person : object_list) {
    person.laugh();
}
```

In this situation you could apply different algorithms inside each concrete class. 
This is a [Strategy Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm).